# How to remove duplicate points using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I want to remove duplicate points and I have **[this model](http://media.getspatial.com/stackexchange/RemoveDuplicatesModel.png)**.

I want to deselect all feature that have the same value of the OID. So I want to add value of the OID in the query of Select by Attribute. How do I incorporate this value in a SQL query ???

I try : "%Feature OID%" = "OID"   (does not work)
and a lot of other tests and nothing work

Someone have an idea?

Comment: It might not be why it's working, but why do you have percent signs (wildcards) around your field name?

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Examples_of_inline_model_variable_substitution/002w0000005w000000/

With this recommandation i test to put % % on my variable to use it... but it's not working :(

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot you are running within Model Builder.. forgot about inline variables. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, I would guess:

```
"OID" = %Feature OID%
```

Should work. As OID is the field you're trying to select from, double quoted as it's probably File GDB. And no quote for the %Feature OID% as OID is a numeric field.

Comment: It's not working, When i try to get the value %Feature OID% in the SQL query, it not recognize him.

Message error:
Thre was an error with the expression.
An invalid SQL statement was used

Comment: If you verify the expression, it's gone a give you an error, but when run, it's gone a work. If it doesn't, please provide more information as the type of Workspace (shapefile, file GDB etc.). I have tested this and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Advanced level license of ArcGIS for Desktop, you may try to go a different route to delete duplicate features based on a common attribute - the **[Delete Identical (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000053000000)** tool should do the trick.

```
arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management(in_dataset, "OID")
```

Comment: I don't have common attribute for use this tool... When I want to use my numeric value %Feature OID% = "OID" it's for remove the oid which is based on the iteration and keep only the OID have the same location. My %Feature OID% is the number of iteration who correspond to my OID. I should call him otherwise